# Loop through with statement

Tags: vb.net, foreach, with-statement

I have the following code:

```
     Public Class Compress


     Public Shared Sub delta()
      Dim results As New Compress()
       With results
         ....
         ...
         ...
       End With
     end sub 
   end class
```

How can I access to elements from with statement? I want to loop like this:

```
    for each element in results
    ....
    Next
```

So, currently I use the following statement after with statement to add each element in the rows:

```
                Sumtable.Rows(Sumtable.Rows.IndexOf(row))("Stdflow" & tmp) = Math.Round(results.flow, 2)
                Sumtable.Rows(Sumtable.Rows.IndexOf(row))("Stdvol" & tmp) = Math.Round(results.vol, 2)
                Sumtable.Rows(Sumtable.Rows.IndexOf(row))("k" & tmp) = Math.Round(results.k, 2)
                Sumtable.Rows(Sumtable.Rows.IndexOf(row))("VOS" & tmp) = Math.Round(results.vos, 2)
                Sumtable.Rows(Sumtable.Rows.IndexOf(row))("μ" & tmp) = Math.Round(results.μ, 2)
```

But I want to loop trough results to obtain one by one elements to avoid unnecessary coding

Comment: `For Each element In results` doesn't work? What error is shown?

Comment: Error BC32023 Expression is of type '', which is not a collection type

Comment: What is `Compress` supposed to represent such that it has items and what do these items represent?  It's quite possible that the appropriate course of action is to inherit `Connection(Of T)`, which already implements `IList(Of T)` and thus provides all the list functionality for you.

Comment: It's possible that what you want is ForEach result in Typeof(Compress).GetProperties(); however this won't return them in the order you want.

Answer (score 0):

Ah yes you need to decorate your class with the correct methods to make this work.

```
 Public Class Compress(Of T)
     Implements IEnumerable(Of T)

     'Provide implementation
 End Class
```

In fact all you need to provide is an implementation of GetEnumerator() that returns something that has MoveNext() As Boolean and Current as T; however people will scream in horror if you don't do it via IEnumerable(Of T).

There's not enough information in the question to provide any hints on what your enumerable needs to do.

Comment: @badscrool, we can't provide you with details because you've provided us with none.  If you want to enumerate an object using a `For Each` loop then you do as instructed. As has already been stated in the answer, you haven't given us enough information for us to give you any more.

Comment: Well, okay, I thought there is some kind of esy-to implement solution, cause I am quite new. I don't understand what type of information do you want. I can put full code if it woul be helpful for you.